# Русский язык некорректно отображается

Tags: android, unicode, text

Я использую вот этот https://stackoverflow.com/a/36255852/7727530.

Всё получается, кроме отображения текстов на русском, отображаются вот так `?????????????????????`,или так

```
%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BF%D0%B
```

пробовал `URLEncoder.encode`, но не помогло, посоветуйте, что делать?

Comment: В проекте задайте кодировку исходников UTF-8 (правый нижний угол студии)

Comment: @Barmaley у меня такой же стоит UTF-8

Comment: Если ты работаешь с БД часто проблемы там.

Comment: @АртурОлеговичПлюх нет просто из приложения отправляю на почту письмо

Comment: если пытаюсь использовать  UrlEncoder.encode(mailbody, "utf-8"), то получаю вот это%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BF%D0%B